# Como passar um valor null no método update() do clancats hydrahon?

Tags: php

Preciso passar um valor nulo para uma coluna (tipo date) do banco de dados mysql, conforme o seguinte código:

```
$birthdate = null;

User::update()
->set('name', $name)
->set('email', $email)
->set('birthdate', $birthdate)                
->where('id', $id)
->execute();
```

Porém é gerado esse erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parece que o hydrahon não aceita que se passe um valor null no seu método update().

Minha dúvida seria: Como eu faria para inserir esse null, na coluna do banco, através do método update() do Hydrahon ?

Vou adicionar a parte do código da lib que é apontado como motivo do erro:

```
public function set($param1, $param2 = null)
{
// do nothing if we get nothing
if (empty($param1))
{
   return $this;
}
        
// when param 2 is not null we assume that only one set is passed
// like: set( 'name', 'Lu' ); instead of set( array( 'name' => 'Lu' ) );
if ( !is_null( $param2 ) )
{
   $param1 = array( $param1 => $param2 );
}
        
// merge the new values with the existing ones.
$this->values = array_merge( $this->values, $param1 ); 
        
// return self so we can continue running the next function
return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Eu não falo português. Usei o Google Tradutor para ajudar a responder essa pergunta. Veja a resposta original em:))*
*[Original answer in english](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64299313/8068675)*

Acho que usar uma array deve funcionar. E também porque é escrever no comentário

> // when param 2 is not null we assume that only one set is passed
> // like: set( 'name', 'Lu' ); instead of **set( array( 'name' => 'Lu' ) );**

```php
$birthdate = null;

User::update()
->set('name', $name)
->set('email', $email)
->set(['birthdate' => $birthdate]) // como isso            
->where('id', $id)
->execute();
```

**Porquê**

```php
if (empty($param1)) { // false: porque não está vazio. Nós passamos
   return $this;
}
```

```php
if ( !is_null( $param2 ) ) { // false: porque é null. Nós passamos
   $param1 = array( $param1 => $param2 );
}
```

Neste ponto, temos `$param1 = ['birthdate' => null]` e `$param2 = null`
Mas desta vez, não temos uma string. Temos uma array.

```php
 // $this->values = array_merge( [], ['birthdate' => null] ); 
    $this->values = array_merge( $this->values, $param1 );
```

---

Indo além, acho que você pode até fazer assim

```php
User::update()
->set([
    'name'      => $name,
    'email'     => $email,
    'birthdate' => $birthdate,
 ])             
->execute();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Sua resposta me ajudou muito e ajudará outros usuários.

Comment: Essa foi a real diferença. ->set(['birthdate' => $birthdate])

Comment: Eu atualizei minha resposta, esqueci o bônus